# Subgroups of semidirect product of groups with coprime order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

Let $G=K \ltimes N$ be a semi-product of two finite groups K and N with coprime order, N being the normal subgroup. My question is, if $K'$ is any subgroup of $G$ with $|K'|=|K|$, are $K'$ and $K$ conjugate? if not, does there exist $f\in \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ such that $f(K)=K'$?

Second Edit: Thanks to Derek Holt's comment below,
the anwser to my first question and hence both the two are yes, by Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem.

Edit: As the comments below, maybe I should say something more on the motivation of this question. It arises in my mind when I am figuring out when two semidirect product $K\ltimes_{\phi_1} N$ and $K\ltimes_{\phi_2} N$ are isomorhic, where $\phi_i: K\to \mathrm{Aut}(N)$ are given. An easy sufficient condition is that  $\phi_1 = \phi_2\circ \alpha$ or $\phi_1 = {\phi_2}^\beta$, or the combination of these two types; here $\alpha \in \mathrm{Aut}(K), \beta\in \mathrm{Aut}(N)$, and ${\phi_2}^\beta$ is the conjugate action of $\phi_2$.

When $K$ is a Sylow p-subgroup, then I can show that this is also a necessary condition for $K\ltimes_{\phi_1} N$ and $K\ltimes_{\phi_2} N$ being isomorphic. In general, I just wonder this holds or not when $|K|$ and $|N|$ are coprime, and it will hold if the anwser to my second question is yes. (Of course, if $K$ Sylow, then clearly the anwser is yes.) But, I can not make any real progress to my question.

Comment: It is [Semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product), not "semi-product". What have you tried so far? Which results can you already use?

Comment: Look up the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem. The answer is interesting: yes, $K$ and $K'$ are conjugate in $G$, but the only known proof uses the  Feit-Thompson Odd Order Theorem.

Comment: I am not immediately sure whether your second question about $f \in {\rm Aut}(G)$ with $f(K)=K'$ is any easier, i.e. whether it has a more elementary proof.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Thanks. I have no progress, except the trivial case when $K$ is a Sylow p-subgroup. And I add my motivation on this question.

Comment: @Shaun Thank you for your kind comment and suggestion. I have added my own motivation and my thought on this question.